# How can I quickly determine all subviews (UIViews) that intersect with a rect?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, subview, intersection, cgrect

I have a view that contains a bunch of subviews.  If the user taps down and drags a selection rect around some of the subviews, is there a faster way of determining which subviews intersect with the selection rect other than iterating through all the subviews of the main parent?

My solution is working by iterating over every subview and using `CGRectIntersectsRect(selectionRect, aSubview.frame)`, but it's too slow for my liking.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. The long answer is that's mainly because `frame` is a *computed* property, a function of `bounds`, `center` and `transform`. Even simple hit-testing is based on iteration.

The real question is why you think it is too slow. If you have hundreds of views, then I suggest caching the views' frames, say, in `touchesBegan:withEvent:` to save on frame calculations and Objective-C message sends every time you have to check the intersection (as you drag the finger).

Perhaps, you can also apply some optimization tricks like sorting the views by their frame origins, but that will complicate your code.

Comment: yeah, I will probably implement some sort of caching option as subviews are added to the main view.  I think I can get it to work a bit faster if I store them ordered somehow in an NSDictionary / NSSet for lookup.  Thanks for the extra info.